# Moving UR_Gazebo through test_move.py

Tags: ros, ur-modern-driver, ur-driver, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not able to move the UR simulation with `ur_gazebo` using action client server like `test_move.py`. MoveIt with gazebo however works fine.

Note: Using `ur_gazebo` on Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo and gazebo 2.x.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289101/moving-ur_gazebo-through-test_move.py/) by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2018-04-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-19**:
I'm confused: you're asking about `ur_gazebo`, but then state that you're using `ur_modern_driver`. The driver is not used with Gazebo. Please clarify and carefully describe your setup.

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-04-19**:
So is there a way of sending joint commands to `ur_gazebo` directly using a python script? I don't want to use MoveIt to control the robot in `ur_gazebo` @gvdhoorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The setup in `ur_gazebo` uses `gazebo_ros_control` to load a `joint_trajectory_controller`. This exposes a standard `FollowJointTrajectory` action server, just like any of the available drivers.

`test_move.py` can make use of that, provided it can find the action topics.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-04-19**:
Perfect, all I had to do was append "arm_controller/" to the subscriber.